# Web UI of the NameNode daemon or data node daemon not working.(Hadoop installed in ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

**All the daemons are running but I am unable to see them in web..

```
hduser@sanjeebpanda:/usr/local/hadoop/yarn_data/hdfs$ ls -ltr
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 3 hduser hadoop 4096 Nov  9 21:13 namenode
drwx------ 2 hduser hadoop 4096 Nov  9 21:14 datanode

hduser@sanjeebpanda:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop$ jps
12240 NameNode
12715 ResourceManager
13056 Jps
12565 SecondaryNameNode
12387 DataNode
5311 JobHistoryServer
12842 NodeManager
```

Core sitexml.

```
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
```

Sanjeeb

Comment: How you are accessing namenode web ui 
?

Comment: I am using http://localhost:50070

Comment: What is the message coming in the browser when you access namenode url ?
Also Post the output of the command 

" sudo netstat -tunalp | grep 50070 "